# Generating a random number in SML

Tags: random, sml

How can you generate a random number from a specific range, for example the integer 34 in the range [1, 100]?

I looked at the [Random structure](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/random.html) but it doesn't give me what I want, at least from what I can understand.

Comment: You're on the right track, have a look at the function `randRange` within the structure `Random`, it should be a perfect fit for what you need

Comment: @waldrumpus Hmm, alright, but I don't understand how to write the arguments. It should be something like `Random.randRange((i, j) s)`, (or I'm completley wrong) but what is `s`?

Comment: Use the function `Rand.rand : (int * int) -> rand` to instantiate a random number generator. Also, be careful to leave out the enclosing parentheses when calling a curried function: `Random.randRange (i, j) s`

Comment: @waldrumpus In Poly/ML there is no support for Random structure. How shall this be done with Poly/ML?

Answer (score 6):

I think you have to use the Random structure in the given link like this ...

```
- val nextInt = Random.randRange (1,100);
- val r = Random.rand (1,1);
- val x1 = nextInt r;
- val x2 = nextInt r;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get 34 integers between 1 and 100, you could use:

```
let
    val seed = Random.rand (123,456)
in
    List.tabulate(34, fn i => Random.randRange (1,100)  seed)
end;
```

Note that the value `seed` is a reference that gets updated with each call to `Random.randRange`.