# How to get a random value for a custom datatype in SML?

Tags: sml, smlnj

How would one return a random value for a data type like below?

```
datatype rank = Jack | Queen | King | Ace | Num of int
```

I am working on a function generate a list of random cards for input to another function, so there is also the need for a similar function for suit.

The output should either be a symbol like Jack, King, etc, or an int from 2 to 9.

The code below is incorrect:

```
fun pick_rank() =
   case Random.randRange(2,13)  of 13 => Ace
               | 12 => King
               | 11 => Queen
               | 10 => Jacl
               | Int v => v
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating a random number in SML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067535/generating-a-random-number-in-sml)

Comment: `Int v => v`  should be `v => Num v`

Answer (score 0):

> How would one return a random value for a data type like below?
>
> ```
> datatype rank = Jack | Queen | King | Ace | Num of int
> ```

I have two answers: Either you generate each value uniquely, or you generate all possible values, shuffle them and pick one. If you just want a random variable in isolation, the former is easiest. But if you want to simulate a card game in which drawing the same card twice is not possible, then you probably want the shuffle.

You can see how I made a [command-line blackjack game](https://github.com/sshine/sml-games/blob/master/blackjack.sml). I'll repeat both approaches here:

```
(* There are 13 card ranks, 4 suits *)
datatype rank
  = Ace | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven
  | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King

datatype suit = Hearts | Clubs | Diamonds | Spades

datatype card = Card of suit * rank

fun concatMap f xs = List.concat (List.map f xs)
fun product xs ys = concatMap (fn x => map (fn y => (x,y)) ys) xs

val allCards = map Card
  (product
     [Hearts,Clubs,Diamonds,Spades]
     [Ace,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten,Jack,Queen,King])

(* Create a new pseudo-random number generator, prng *)
val prng = Random.newgen ()

(* rlist determines a random index in [0 ; length xs[. *)
fun rlist xs = Random.range (0, length xs) prng

(* remove removes the n'th element of a list *)
fun remove (_, []) = raise Domain
  | remove (0, card::library) = library
  | remove (n, card::library) = card::remove (n-1, library);

(* randomtake removes and returns the i'th (random) element of a list *)
fun randomtake library =
    let val i = rlist library
        val card = List.nth (library, i)
        val rest = remove (i, library)
    in
      (card, rest)
    end

(* Shuffling is done by removing random cards until there are no cards left *)
fun shuffle [] = []
  | shuffle cards =
    let val (c,r) = randomtake cards
    in
      c :: shuffle r
    end
```

Using these functions, you could pick a single random card by doing `randomtake allCards`, or you could pick any amount of random cards without picking the same card by first `shuffle allCards` and pick the top elements.

Note that these are not efficient methods. As an exercise, you could implement the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Would it be possible to give an example just for the case of suit = Spades | Clubs | Hearts | Diamonds? I guess I could use the code as is and just fill a list n times with cards in the form of suit*rank.

Comment: What would that example demonstrate that the current example isn't demonstrating?